# Need to fade in fade out text in sequence

Tags: html, css

I came across text that fades in and fades out one after the other.

In developer mode, I was able to see the opacity vary for the texts from 0 to 1 to 0 in a sequence. How is this achieved?

```
<div class="text" style="opacity: 0;">The</div> 
<div class="text" style="opacity: 0;">Nomads</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? You should first try it yourself and if you have any specific doubt in you code then you should ask that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simplistic approach using CSS3 Animations and the `keyframes` property (Please note I've edited this answer to include improvements from Frits' comment)

Although you might need to tweak it a little as

> a text which fade in fade out one after the other

Is a pretty lose specification.

```css
/* Define the key frames for animating the fade in / fade out */

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* attach the animations to the elements via their id attribute using a delay of 0s and 50% of the runtime respectively */

#one {
  animation: fade 3s infinite 0s;
}

#two {
  animation: fade 3s infinite 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<p id="one">
  This line of text will fade out as the next lines fade in
</p>
<p id="two">
  This line of text will fade in as the previous lines fade out
</p>
```

Comment: +1 for sticking to CSS. If I may make a suggestion however, you can remove the keyframes at `25%` and `75%` on your keyframes because those values would get hit at those intervals in any case. You can also use the same keyframe on both elements, and use a delay in your animation syntax on the second element to be half of the animation time (i.e. 1.5s) - here's an example (https://jsfiddle.net/6qy8ot4h/) feel free to incorporate it into your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Frits - yeah happy to update the answer to reflect these, it was just something i knocked up live so didn't put too much in the way of optimisation in place

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

*obviously I'm going to use `JQuery`*:

```
jQuery('<div_name>').css('opacity', '<opacity_value>');
```